# Temporary "active" border in XMonad

Tags: xmonad

I'm trying out `noBorders` and `smartBorders` in XMonad.

Is there any way to make the "active" border appear only when the "mod" key is pressed, and show no borders otherwise?  Maybe that's all that is necessary to get oriented when switching focus.

Alternatively, what about making all borders disappear a few seconds after changing focus?